# ffmpeg streaming (mpegts vs rtmp) error

Tags: ffmpeg

This works:

```
ffmpeg -i  test.mp4 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -f mpegts udp://x.x.x.x:1935/video/test
```

but this doesn't:

```
ffmpeg -i  test.mp4 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 1984k -bufsize 3968k -vf "format=yuv420p" -g 60 -f flv rtmp://x.x.x.x:1935/video/test
```

I get:

```
RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 10061 (Unknown error)
rtmp://x.x.x.x:1935/video/test: Unknown error occurred
```

yes, I have a server (Nimble) that is actively listening to RTMP connections and it doesn't see any RTMP streams incoming.

Even when running ffmpeg on the server machine with 127.0.0.1, I get the same error.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using network sniffing to verify that the traffic is (1) being sent from the originating server and (2) being received at the intended client machine.

Wireshark is a good network sniffer program to use on both ends. Or you could use a Linux utility like "tcpdump".  Take a look to see whether the captured traffic looks "normal", that it, without too many retries or errors - if it is happening at all.

If there is no traffic being received at the receiving end then (1) double check that the IP addresses are correct and (2) check that the port is open on the receiver.

If the receiving end is receiving OK but the stream never gets past the first message or so, then check that the sending system allows the responses from the receiver to be passed in, as it is probably using TCP by default, which requires two-way communications.

If that works - in other words if you successfully see the stream coming out of the sender and being received by the client machine - then you could try using VLC on the client for receiving.